# Hugo blog + netlify deployment + custom domain = page not found..frustrating stuff

Tags: hugo, netlify

I keep getting a page not found error, no matter what I do.
Both urls, my custom domain (https://dittmaraz.life) and netlify's subdomain (https://compassionate-lumiere-512b58.netlify.com) both give me 'page not found'. This is a error page that says:

Page Not Found
    Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site.

Here's the github [repo](https://github.com/dittmaraz/dittmaraz-hugoblog).

No build errors. There's one blog post and its draft property is set to false. netlify's build settings are set to the initial settings.
Also, config.toml's baseURL is set to 'https://dittmaraz.life/'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the default deploy folder `public`, but your config.toml for the site is deploying to `docs`

```
baseURL = "https://dittmaraz.life/"
languageCode = "en-us"
title = "dittmaraz"
theme = "mediumish-gohugo-theme"
summaryLength = 25
copyright = "2019 dittmaraz.life"
enableEmoji = true
publishDir = "docs"
```

You can change this in the `app.netlify.com` admin console for the site or create a `netlify.toml` at the root of your repository

`netlify.toml`

```
[build]
  command = "hugo"
  publish = "docs"
```

Alternatively, you can just deploy it to `public` by changing the value from `docs` to `public`

Comment: if you have this problem and it does not have the solution that @talves posted, check out this article about general reasons for this problem and how to troubleshoot here:  https://community.netlify.com/t/common-issue-i-ve-deployed-my-site-but-i-still-see-page-not-found/125

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues:

**Wrong publishDir:**

As [Talves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55694178/7665252) already points out, the content is generated into /docs instead of the default /public directory. Easy fix, remove the *publishDir* from **config.toml** by commenting it out:

```
#publishDir = "docs"
```

**Generated content in Git repository:**

Netlify will generate your site, it should not be in the Git repository.

1. remove both directories /public and /docs
2. commit to Git
3. add .gitignore with this content:

   /public/
   /resources/